# Glitch on UITextField resignFirstResponder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

We have one UITextField on our application that is "jumping" after calling resignFirstResponder on it.

Here's a gif with the glitch:

[image]

And here's the code that triggers it:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    //[self searchContent];
    [_searchField resignFirstResponder];

    return NO;
}
```

It's weird because I commented out all my keyboardWillHide and keyboardWillChangeFrame code, and this still happens on iOS 10.

iOS 9 and 8 are working fine.

Edit:
Just created a new UITextField and put it in the screen. When calling resignFirstResponder on it, I get the same glitched behavior. Running on iOS 10 GM

Comment: What does that call to `[self searchContent]` do?

Comment: rmaddy: searchContent isn't related to the bug, commenting it out has the same behavior